# Django autocomplete light: field not populated

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I've installed "Django autocomplete light" and now following this tutorial: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/tutorial.html

Here is my code so far:

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'dal',
'dal_select2',
'garages',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

**models.py**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Person(models.Model):
    birth_country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.birth_country
```

**views.py**

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Country.objects.none()
        qs = Country.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs


def create_person(request):
    person_form = PersonForm()
    c = {
        'person_form': person_form,
    }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('garages/person_form.html', c,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'birth_country': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='garages:country-autocomplete')
    }
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^country-autocomplete/$', CountryAutocomplete.as_view(), name='country-autocomplete'),
url(r'^new_person/$', views.create_person, name='create_person'),
```

**person_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ person_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/static/collected/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

**RESULT**

[image]

**The problem**: 'Birth country' field is not populated and also I cannot type.

What's the reason? 
Is it possible that the cause is generated by .js loaded on base.html?

In base.html is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dont know why this was downvoted. This is a helpful question and seems to be a common issue faced when trying to use django-autocomplete-light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was simple: adding some plugin's javascrips and css

```
<link href="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/select2.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem, where did you put the javascripts and css?

Comment: in person_form.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include {{form.media}} in the template.

Comment: To be more clear, make sure to include jquery.js BEFORE form.media ! This is the only way it worked for me.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

{{ form.media }}`