# GET /static/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1832

Tags: python, autocomplete, django-3.1

I am trying to create a dropdown of countires which can be searchable based on [this doc](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html), however almost disappointed to find any solution by googling.

I am using `django-cities-light` package and django-autocomplete-light, and all I need to do is creating a field of countries/cities and populating it in a form and making it searchable,

in setting.py and installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'app.apps.MyownAppConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'tinymce',
    'cities_light',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
  ]
```

in models.py:

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
from cities_light.models import Country
class Post(models.Model):
     ...
     descript = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
     location = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

in views.py:

```
class CountryAutocomplete(LoginRequiredMixin, autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Country.objects.none()

        qs = Country.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        return qs
```

In forms.py:

```
class postform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        
        fields ='__all__'
        
        
        exclude = ['date_published']

        widgets = {
            'location': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete' , attrs={'data-placeholder': 'select location...', 'data-minimum-input-length': 4})
        }

        search_fields = ['name']
```

and in postform.html:

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
     <form id="dropdownForm" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="content-section">
                    
                    {{ form.descript }}
                    <label>location</label>
                    {{ form.location }}

                </div>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
   </main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

{{ form.media }}
{% endblock content %}
```

and in url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [path('country-autocomplete/', CountryAutocomplete.as_view(model=Country), name='country-autocomplete')]
```

But what I get is this:

[image: does not load countries and seach box]

Moreover, in terminal I see this msg:

```
"GET /static/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1832
```

I also had a look to all available questions in SO, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032372/django-autocomplete-light-field-not-populated), but didn't help that much. Could you please help me with this problem a bit?

Comment: Dropdown: UI element rendered by a `<select>` tag; Dropbox: a commercial file sharing cloud service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weird error to me. If you are using `venv`, try to remove the `django-autocomplete-light` folder and again replace it with a [new](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git) one, and then check if you still get the same error! Also in your `base.html` file, make sure the `.js` links are in order, because extra script could be loaded on the top of the previews one, so the developer should take care of them. It should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<link href="{% static '/autocomplete_light/select2.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Try to use webkit inspector to check if jquery is not loaded twice.